# multi forms in one frame npyscreen

Tags: python-3.x, tui, npyscreen

Hello I have started learning `npyscreen` for **tui** and I have searched the internet for `**multi forms in one frame for npyscreen** cant find an answer 
im trying to make apps that look like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after searching some more found that link 
[here](https://medium.com/@bad_day/create-tui-on-python-71377849879d)

helped me alot